# Installing a python 3.7 virtual environment on a Linux machine with python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, virtual-machine, virtualenv

I wonder how I can install a python 3.7 virtual environment on a Linux machine that currently has python 2.7? I also do not have `sudo` privilege.

Comment: You have to have python 3.7 installed to create a virtualenv for it. If you cannot install it on the host think about a virtual machine or a container. Contact admins of the host or find out another host.

Comment: Thanks, @phd Is it possible to install python 3.7 without having `sudo` privilege?

Comment: Very much depends on the list of libraries installed on the host. If there're not enough libraries or if those libraries lack development files (headers) it would be hard to compile Python from sources — either it couldn't be compiled at all or would lack a lot of modules like `zlib`. One of these libraries — OpenSSL — very important; without it `pip` wont work (PyPI requires HTTPS connection).

Comment: Well, you could try to install all those libraries locally, in your personal account. But that'd be a huge job. Look at https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts — there is build script `build-python3.sh`.

Comment: Thanks! @phd I am wondering if it is feasible to build a virtual environment with Python 2.7 first, and then upgrade python in that virtual environment?

Comment: Python virtualenvs are not containers. You cannot upgrade Python version in a virtualenv without first having that version outside of the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do this with `conda`:

First, install `conda` in your Linux account:

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ conda update --all
```

Then create a virtual environment with `conda` while specifying Python version:

```
$ conda create -n myenv python=3.7
$ conda activate hou-env
```

After that, running `python -V` in the command line will return Python 3.7.13

Comment: Agreed, Conda is the best way to do this.To expand - on Linux, installing a Python version over another is not recommended as installed programs are built for (and expect) the original Python version. The newer Python version will be added as an environment variable, potentially causing conflicts. This doesn't happen with Conda.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install python without sudo privileges, then just download a compressed version of python 3, decompress it, run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).